# In What Order Does Windows 10 Come Out?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a Windows 8 computer and I heard Windows 10 came out recently. I checked my computer today and it says Windows 10 might come in a couple days to a couple weeks. My question is, in what order does Windows 10 come out? Why doesn't Microsoft release it all at once? When should I expect to get the update? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Windows 8 do you have? I have installed Windows 10 Home right 4 hours ago.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have Windows 8.1 I am not home at the moment so I don't know any details of the version

Comment: Anyone can download the [tool released by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to upgrade now...